# What's the best practices for making a Web application to support HTTP/2

Tags: http2

I'm trying out [HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/) and would like to know if there's any best practices for making a web application take advantages of the new protocol in both:

1. Server side and
2. Client side

And... where (and when?) should I start? What are the least effort changes to take effort of HTTP/2

**Update:**

Assumption : Users are already using browser that support HTTP/2.

**Update 2:**

Some good resources on this topic:

- https://http2.github.io/faq/
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/7-tips-for-faster-http2-performance/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/

Comment: First of all you should decide if your target users / customers will use devices / browsers that support http/2.

Comment: I'm assuming they have (eventually they will)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any changes to your apps to deploy HTTP/2: most things will work out of the box.

That said, here are a few tips that apply mostly if you are starting from scratch:

- Start developing your application using HTTPS. You don't want to have problems with your URLs when you deploy your application because fetching some resources over http:// (e.g. Google fonts or any other CDN resources) does not work anymore. It takes five minutes with some tools (just google "Five minutes to HTTPS development URLs").
- Consider if you want to host some resources that you would normally link to a public CDN in your own server. The main performance reason with HTTP/2 for linking to some assets in a CDN, if you are not hosting your entire site on that CDN, is that those resources may be already in the user's cache. If they are not, opening a new connection [takes in average half a second](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/shimmercat/art_timings/blob/master/TimingsOfResourceLoads.ipynb#How-the-total-times-are-distributed-for-connections-with-SSL).
- Don't set up bundling. Set up instead HTTP/2 Push. And then go and grab your favourite module manager. Give a try also to web components and PolymerJS. They are simply awesome when you are not concerned about bundling and round-trips.

If you are using a server that uses machine learning for configuring HTTP/2 Push automatically (e.g, ShimmerCat), then a third tip is to keep the structure of your web pages predictable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What do you mean by keep the structure of pages predictable?

Comment: @Ved Say that you are generating pages dynamically, with urls /my/product/category/?prod_id=123456 . Normally all those pages will use a similar set of resources (JS, CSS, images,fonts, you name it). That's what I meant. Versus, say, using EmberJS for products with an even ID and AngularjS for products with a prime ID. The only reason for the regularity is to allow some tools to save you optimization work by learning which assets you *usually* include in your page.